# Need a service that build calendar (iCal, outlook) links

Tags: joomla, calendar

The users of my Joomla based site often need to create an artice where the post some appointment dates. Now they would like to have an easy way to add calendar links for the most popular calendars ICal, Outlook, Thunderbird, Google Calendar. Do you know of a simple way how they could do that? Maybe there is a joomla plugin for that? Or maybe there is an online service somewhere where the user could enter the dates and then urls for the various calendars are created. Sort of lie ImageShack but for calenders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the different calendar extensions available for Joomla?

I would take a look at the list [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/calendars).

The first one in the list, [Zap Calendar](http://www.zapcalendar.com/) sounds like it might meet your requirements. Although it is commercial!