# Javascript library to create calendar uri/links to Google, Yahoo, Outlook , iCal?

Tags: calendar, yahoo, javascript, icalendar, google-calendar-api

I have seen a very specific and professional web page widget (e.g. http://whatsnextlectures-work.eventbrite.com/ and meetup.com). Please help me find the library that creates the links.

I have looked at [Need a service that build calendar (iCal, outlook) links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348590/need-a-service-that-build-calendar-ical-outlook-links), but that answer seems to address the need for an on-screen calendar, not just the links.

thanks

Comment: Hello Mr.Richard, did you get the solution, even I am looking for the solution for the same problem, if you have the solution please let me know.

Comment: No solution so far. I have tried to find a public or commercial library, but I think I will have to write one myself.

Comment: But I was able to find a library. Even I was looking for the same kinda of library. just go through this link http://tardate.blogspot.com/2010/10/add-to-calendar-with-jquery-widget.html

Comment: I used this as a reference for how to do this in the modern variations: it's very good: https://github.com/carlsednaoui/add-to-calendar-buttons

Note that repeating events aren't well supported (or at least, not well documented if they are) via url for Yahoo and Outlook Live.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can create below registry entry and anchor link/button to open the outlook calendar

below is the markup

```
<button id="outlookCalendarBtn" onclick="window.open('outlookwebcal:')">
   Open Outlook Calendar
</button>
```

Create below registry entry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal]
@="URL:Outlook Add Internet Calendar"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlookwebcal\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\office16\\Outlook.exe\" /select outlook:calendar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I was looking for the same library Mr.Richard but after reaching for 3 days I finally found this. http://tardate.blogspot.com/2010/10/add-to-calendar-with-jquery-widget.html

But iCal is not included in this library you need to add it explicitly.